# How to link matrix subgroup to list of colours? in R?

Tags: r, matrix

So I have a subgroup of number ranging from 1 - 6 which I want to link to a list of colours but I can't seem to link them correctly.

My code looks subgroup matrix looks like

```
          PCA_Model    Subgroup
ACTL6A    Numeric,4    3       
ADAM9     Numeric,16   4       
ADAMTS1   Numeric,4    3       
ADCY7     FALSE        3       
AIMP2     Numeric,8036 3       
ALKBH7    Numeric,4    3       
ALOX5AP   Numeric,16   1       
AMPD3     Numeric,4    1       
APITD1    FALSE        1
```

And I am trying to link them using this piece of code

```
PCA_Model <- prcomp(t(K_means_Model$centers))
samples_names <- K_means_Model$cluster
# Bind sample names to their subgroup
pca_matrix <- cbind(PCA_Model, "Subgroup"=samples_names)
# Link dataframe to color
colours <- as.character(factor(pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"], levels = paste0("C", 1:6),labels = c("blue", 
"red", "yellow", "green", "black", "pink")))
```

But everytime I try link the colours object just produces na values. Would anyone be able to suggest a better way of doing this?

All help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would do something on the line of

```
df <- data.frame(
     PCA_model = c("Numeric,4","Numeric,16","Numeric,5","Numeric,1","Numeric,1","Numeric,3","Numeric,64","Numeric,123"),
     Subgroup= c(3,4,3,3,1,2,5,6))

> df
    PCA_model Subgroup
1   Numeric,4        3
2  Numeric,16        4
3   Numeric,5        3
4   Numeric,1        3
5   Numeric,1        1
6   Numeric,3        2
7  Numeric,64        5
8 Numeric,123        6

# generate the vector of colours
colo <- c(brewer.pal(6,"Set3"))   # using RColorBrewer (library(RColorBrewer))
colo <- c(brewer.pal(length(unique(df$Subgroup)),"Set3")) # if you don't know how many colours you need
colo <- c("blue","red", "yellow", "green", "black", "pink")) # like you did
names(col) <- unique(df$Subgroup)

> colo
    3         4         1         2         5         6 
"#8DD3C7" "#FFFFB3" "#BEBADA" "#FB8072" "#80B1D3" "#FDB462"
```

You can then pass `colo` to ggplot or other libraries and the colours will  follow the values of `df$Subgroup`